# PHP format number from CSV file after upload

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I just successfully uploaded and read through on a csv file using PHP Codigniter. What I want to do now is to format the numbers for example:

> 6.06861E+11

to

> 606861000000

before inserting it to the database. How should I do this in PHP? Thank you.

Comment: Do you see that number in excel or where? Your column is set to a `bigint` as well? `606861000000` will exceed `int`.

Comment: is the number stored as "6.06861E+11" or just displayed as "6.06861E+11"

Comment: in the csv file the number is already formatted to "6.06861E+11"

Comment: How did it get to that format? I'd fix the issue at the point of creation.

Answer (score 1):

PHP understands scientific notation, you just need to let it know that you want it formatted as a number. You can accomplish this by subtracting zero from it like so.

```
<?php
$x = '6.06861E+11';
echo $x - 0;
?>
```

Displays -> 606861000000

Comment: No Problem. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to convert from exponential to the right number format:

```
     function easy_number_format($number, $dec_point, $thousands_sep)
       {
       $number = rtrim(sprintf('%f', $number), "0");
       if (fmod($nummer, 1) != 0) {                      
       $array_int_dec = explode('.', $number);
       } else { 
       $array_int_dec= array(strlen($nummer), 0);
       }
       (strlen($array_int_dec[1]) < 2) ? ($decimals = 2) : ($decimals =                             strlen($array_int_dec[1]));
      return number_format($number, $decimals, $dec_point,                  $thousands_sep);
        }
```

Comment: credit where credit is due: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php#103834